# replace while loop with range function

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can I replace while loop with range function. I am using following code

```
check = 0
while check<5:
      print check
      check+=2
```

I am writing in following way

```
for _check in range(0,5,2):
     print _check
```

is it correct way?

**> Editing My question**

if I am not using _check variable inside for loop. Can I avoid to declare also

Comment: maybe just a typo, but there seems to be a mistake in the first sample proposed: the last line should ne check+=2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are using `range()` correctly, but you may want to use [`xrange()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) instead here:

```
for check in xrange(0, 5, 2):
    print check
```

`xrange()` produces the same results when iterated over, but doesn't build a whole list of all possible indices first, and as a result uses less memory:

```
>>> range(0, 5, 2)
[0, 2, 4]
>>> xrange(0, 5, 2)
xrange(0, 6, 2)
```

Since the end-point is not included in the values, it doesn't matter if you use `5` or `6` here as the endpoint, it is just calculated for you from the input parameters.

If you are not using the loop variable, you can use `_` to indicate that you are ignoring it in the loop. This is just a naming convention:

```
for _ in xrange(0, 5, 2):
    # do something 3 times.
```

in which case you may as well just calculate how many indices there are between 0 and 5 with a step of two and simplify your loop to:

```
upper_limit, step = 5, 2
for _ in xrange((upper_limit - 1 + step) // step):
    # do something 3 times.
```

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding the original while loop, using check = check + 1**

```
for x in xrange(5):
    print x
```

See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more information on control flow tools (like loops).

**EDIT**

If you want to increment by 2 during each iteration, you can use the above code with the increment specified:

```
for x in xrange(0,5,2):
    print x
```

Comment: The edit corrected the syntax, it was clear (to me at least) that the OP wanted the `while` loop to increment in steps of two. Or was there a grace-period edit that changed the `check + 1` into a `check + 2`?

Comment: Yes martijn - the original question had check += 1 in the while loop.